# Getting earphone out from music player

Tags: arduino, amplifier, audio

I've made an arduino based audio spectrum analyzer & it requires audio input from a music player/laptop/phone earphone out.

I've tested this with earphone out from my audio player (Yamaha MCR-B142) and it worked fine.

Sadly when I connect earphone out to the Arduino, sound stops coming from speakers.

I want to listen to audio from music player while the signal goes to the Arduino. I understand this is the nature of the earphone out. So I tried to get output from speaker out.

But the amplifier (YDA164 amplifier IC) has differential outs and I'm confused about getting a single ended output from that.

Amplifier maximum output is 15W @ 6 ohms.

What I want is to get an earphone out level signal from the music player.

Please assist me as I've spent so many hours to reach thus far.

Let me know if the information is unclear.

I learned lot of things through this project.

Comment: This is not specifically answerable but you probably want a series coupling capacitor andd to take signal from the amplifier input.

Comment: Thanks Chris, tried to reach input stage & its beyond my capabilities with so many tiny smd components.I noticed a similar question answered here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344651/attenuate-75w-speaker-to-line-in .. Can I join my question to that question? Thanks

Comment: Trying to clarify what you mean: You have a stereo sound system. Looking at the product page, it has detachable speakers, Bluetooth out, and headphone out.  You want to listen to music through those speakers at the same time that your arduino is attached and "listening" to the same music? Is this correct?

Comment: One thing that I can't tell from the product page is whether the detachable speakers are wired or wireless.  That will likely matter to people who are able to answer.

Comment: Thanks All for the replies. Yes it has detachable outputs for speakers (but they are differential outputs), headphone out (speaker sound will cut off when a earphone plug inserted) & Bluetooth input. What I want is, get a audio out to feed in to arduino while listening to music coming from speakers.Please let me know if my reply is unclear

Comment: Any other solution please ? @dwaynereid Please assist if possible. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are really asking for. But let me try to answer it. What I understand is, you want an audio output which you can listen to as well as give it to Arduino at the same time.
For taking out the Audio from, say, your mobile, use an aux cable. Now this cable has generally 4 wires. One for ground, one for mic, one for left ear sound, and one for right ear's sound.

[image]
Image source: circuitbasics.com

One end of this cable goes inside your mobile phone and the other to a audio socket. Now the audio socket, depending on its type, may have 4 pins. These 4 pins are connected to the corresponding 4 wires in aux cable. Some of them do not have the mic pin out. But you yourself have to find out which pins are for what purpose. 
[image]
Image source: ebay.com

So all you have to do is take ground pin and any of one (right or left) of the audio pin. Give them to your Arduino. Use the same two pins(Gnd and audio) to connect to an another audio socket. Your earphones will be inserted in this second audio socket. So you can listen to the sound and give it to the Arduino at the same time. You can use an amplifier if you wish to listen to music.

Comment: Thanks Bhuvnesh, Apologies for not clarifying my requirements . I don't use earphone out to listen music through this player. I want to use its speakers while the earphone out send its  audio signal to arduino. But the earphone jack has complex mechanism disabling this. So, I'm trying to get an output through speaker outs.